# neo4jClient foreach create

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

How to create multiple nodes in a single transaction using neo4jClient.The Current code works fine but is a bit slower

```
           foreach (UserInfo _ui in users)
       {            
            client.Cypher.Create("(n:User{param})")
            .WithParam("param", _ui).ExecuteWithoutResults();                
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cypher, you can [create multiple nodes in a single transaction](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-create-mutiple-nodes-with-properties) using a parameter that is a collection of maps. Since your `users` variable already seems to be such a collection, try replacing your loop with:

```
client.Cypher.Create("(n:User{param})")
    .WithParam("param", users).ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Thanx alot Cybersam,ur suggestion helped alot.....The problem now is out of memory exception while creating nodes.

Comment: User collection has around 2 lakh records,i can insert 5000 records at a time,but how to fix the size,i mean sometimes it works with 10k nodes at a time.

Comment: If your parameter is very big, it is not surprising that you will eventually run out of memory. However, you might be able to increase the number of records that run reliably by changing the neo4j configuration. You can start by looking at the batch insert example on <http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-io-examples.html#configuration-batchinsert>.